# Huge array on C++

Tags: c++

I solve some problem using C++. I have a huge array of double-s. It is used during all the process of solution, the program adresses to its different parts both reading them and changing ones.

What type of container is the most proper for this situation? It must get access to the elemetns quilckly and store the data properly.

Is it good idea to use
`std::vector<double>`?

Comment: More information about what you are trying to do would be useful. As far as "does `std::vector` have random access lookups?" the answer is yes.

Comment: `vector` could be good, but you haven't really provided us with enough information to consider the alternatives. What is your problem? Are you using `vector`, but is is somehow not good enough? Please elaborate :)

Comment: What's the question? The answer to should you use `std::vector` is almost always yes.

Comment: You need a quick access, alright, but what do you need to do _exactly_ ? Also be cautious with `std::vector` behaviour to avoid a huge number of moves/copies

Comment: Also, do you have a fixed or variable number of doubles ? Do you know how many before hand ?

Comment: Please define "huge".

Comment: @Mgetz Seems you are considering very small sample space...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what and how you would perform operation on your container. Like:-

Associative container like std::set would be efficient in this case as they are implemented in terms of balanced binary tree.

But a sorted vector outperforms associative container in some situations on the basis of locality of reference.

If operation on your data structure are clearly categorized into below sub-operations then use sorted vector:-

1) There would be insert/delete to set up the data structure.

2) After data structure is setup only look up operations would be predominant.

NOTE: You also should initialize your vector large enough to avoid any re-allocations in between.